# What's energy method?

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations

When searching about PDE, I sometimes see the word "energy method". I want to know this method but there is no wikipedia page about it.

Is there a good web page or book about this topic?

Comment: You can check The Energy Method, Stability, and Nonlinear Convection (Applied Mathematical Sciences) 2nd Edition for a comprehensive introduction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose we have a parabolic PDE. Basically we exploit the structure of the PDE to create an energy-like functional $E(t)$ that is non-increasing over time, giving an a-priori estimate for important quantities (like the $L^2$ norm) of the solution $u$ of our PDE. This can be used to prove uniqueness and other properties of $u$.

The first few pages of this [lecture note](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Ehunter/pdes/ch6.pdf) has a nice example of the method. Most PDE textbooks also treat this subject quite well, e.g. [Evans' Partial Differential Equations](https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-19-r).